# smartd custom logfile on systemd + journald based system

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, logs, systemd-journald, smart

An excerpt from [smartd manpage](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartd.8.html) reads:

> **`-l FACILITY, --logfacility=FACILITY`**
>   `Uses syslog facility FACILITY to log the messages from smartd. Here FACILITY is one of local0, local1, ..., local7, or daemon [default]. If this command-line option is not used, then by default messages from smartd are logged to the facility daemon.`

Followed by steps how to accomplish this on a **syslog** based system.

Apparently, if Arch Linux is up-to-date, it runs `journald` in conjunction with `systemd` for the same purpose. For the latter, I cannot find a way to configure facilities or whatnot.

How to give `smartd` a logfile of it's own in a `journald` environment?

---

Mirrored from [Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1308610).

Comment: Maybe a chance: you can run a "normal" logging system which supports facility as I do. Is it acceptable for you or have any reason to avoid all other logging system?

Comment: Well, Arch Linux and majority of it's packages are now based around journald. While [they allow to run syslog in parallel to journald](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Journald_in_conjunction_with_syslog), I wanted to avoid the solution. Just for the sake of keeping everything concise.

Comment: I'm using metalog with facilities (because own scripts run 'logger -t' to logging) and it works well (parallel with journald).